# c#: Trying to inject dictionary key and values into an Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, dictionary, export

I am trying to export the summed up values into an excel file.  I could easily do this with a CSV file but doing so with excel is difficult for me because I could only inject one value into a cell at a time.  And I have to export it to an xlsx extension.

What I am trying to do here is set the first parameter as the row number, second parameter as the column number, and the third parameter as the value to be injected there.

```
           int iColumn = 1;
           excel.WriteToSheet(int value of row, iColumn, key);
           excel.WriteToSheet(int value of row, iColumn + 1, iSumOpen);
           excel.WriteToSheet(int value of row, iColumn + 2, iSumBuy);
           excel.WriteToSheet(int value of row, iColumn + 3, iSumSell);
           excel.WriteToSheet(int value of row, iColumn + 4, iSumSettleMM);
```

Here is the entire method.  I have tried to change the row value to key.count, using a for loop and making it key.element(i), and have had no luck finding the logical way to do this, partly because I am inexperienced with dictionaries and the methods of it.

```
 public void printToExcel(string vOutputPath)
    {
        string sExcelPath = @"C:\Users\jhochbau\Desktop\Test.xlsx";
        ExcelHelper excel = new ExcelHelper(sExcelPath);
        excel.OpenWorkbook();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<DataRecord>> kvp in vSummaryResults)
        {
            string key = kvp.Key; //assigns key

            List<DataRecord> list = kvp.Value;  //assigns value


            int iSumOpen = 0;
            int iSumBuy = 0;
            int iSumSell = 0;
            double iSumSettleMM = 0;

            foreach (DataRecord rec in list)
            {
                if (vSummaryResults.ContainsKey(key))
                {

                    iSumOpen += rec.open;
                    iSumBuy += rec.buy;
                    iSumSell += rec.sell;
                    iSumSettleMM += rec.settleMM;

                }

                else
                {
                    vSummaryResults.Add(key, list);

                }

            }
            //WriteToSheet params: int row, int column, and value injected
            //need to create some counters here to move the rows and columns?


                int iColumn = 1;
                excel.WriteToSheet(int value of row, iColumn, key);
                excel.WriteToSheet(int value of row, iColumn + 1, iSumOpen);
                excel.WriteToSheet(int value of row, iColumn + 2, iSumBuy);
                excel.WriteToSheet(int value of row, iColumn + 3, iSumSell);
                excel.WriteToSheet(int value of row, iColumn + 4, iSumSettleMM);


        }
    }
```

Also the output should look like this:

Account    iSumOpen   iSumBuy   iSumSell    iSumSettleMM

Account2...

Account3...

Comment: Where does your ExcelHelper class come from?

Comment: It is a class in my project.  The class just handles the initializing, opening, writing and closing of Excel.  Didn't think it would be necessary here?

Comment: Is there a method for next key?

Comment: Ok another thought.  IS there a way to get the index value of a key?
So something like dictionary.Keys.CurrentIndex>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a counter starting at the first row, if row 0 is your header row then start with 1, and use a foreach loop on the dictionary.

```
public void printToExcel(string vOutputPath)
{
    string sExcelPath = @"C:\Users\jhochbau\Desktop\Test.xlsx";
    ExcelHelper excel = new ExcelHelper(sExcelPath);
    excel.OpenWorkbook();
    int curRow = 1; //initialize to your starting row for data printing
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<DataRecord>> kvp in vSummaryResults)
    {
        string key = kvp.Key; //assigns key

        List<DataRecord> list = kvp.Value;  //assigns value

        int iSumOpen = list.Sum(x => x.open);
        int iSumBuy = list.Sum(x => x.buy);
        int iSumSell = list.Sum(x => x.sell);
        double iSumSettleMM = list.Sum(x => x.settleMM);
        //No need to check vSummaryResults.ContainsKey(key) here, because you already took the key from the dictionary 
        //in 'string key = kvp.Key;' so you know it exists unless you've removed it
        //also don't need to bother with a loop here, use LINQ instead
        //foreach (DataRecord rec in list)

        //WriteToSheet params: int row, int column, and value injected
        //need to create some counters here to move the rows and columns?
        int iColumn = 1;
        excel.WriteToSheet(curRow, iColumn, key);
        excel.WriteToSheet(curRow, iColumn + 1, iSumOpen);
        excel.WriteToSheet(curRow, iColumn + 2, iSumBuy);
        excel.WriteToSheet(curRow, iColumn + 3, iSumSell);
        excel.WriteToSheet(curRow, iColumn + 4, iSumSettleMM);
        curRow += 1; //increment to the next data row in the sheet
    }
}
```